# Basic android if statement force close

Tags: java, android, if-statement

When I run this code with the if statement in it.  It crashes when I press the button in my app.  I can't figure out why, if I remove the if statement it will output the text no problem.

```
public void onButtonClickGuess (View v) {
    EditText Guess1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView result1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //turn r into a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive)
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
    int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(Guess1.getText().toString());
    if (i1 > guess1){
        result1.setText("Too Low");
    }else if (i1<guess1){
        result1.setText("Too High");
    }else (i1 == guess1){
        result1.setText("NICE GUESS!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the logcat? What error does it show you?

Comment: Look at your `else` statement. It has a syntax error. You don't write the condition in an `else` statement.

Comment: Looking for the logcat now.

Comment: B. Naeem, I tried both ways and get the same problem.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  Figured it out.  Where my xml file referenced this button the gui put the activity in the xml.  Removed that and it worked.

Comment: What u enter in the Guess1 view. Is it a Number or something else. You can NumberFormatException if the view is empty or not given a Number value.

Comment: @TwizzleBizzle Feel free to provide an answer to your question below with your solution

Comment: What a short and bad code I see. You are asking for troubles if you will be keeping that "style" in future. Vars like `Guess1` and `guess1`. Also this code will not compile due to syntax error (missing `if`)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I'm just proving out basic concepts.  It's easy to just game it guess1 I guess.  Bad habbit haha

Answer (score 0):

The crash wasn't due to the if statement (which was incorrect above, the else statement had a condition).

The error was when I selected onClick in the .xml design it added (MainActivity) to the end of the string.  I deleted this so it read android:onClick="onButtonClickReset" instead of android:onClick="onButtonClickReset (MainActivity)"

That fixed it.